# Flink Solution Suggestion

Tags: apache-flink

I have an object stream（of thousands types）, each object have time and some other fields like

`A(a1,a2,t),B(b1,b2,b3,t),C(c1,c2,C3,t),D(d1,d2,t)`,

the object comes one by one.

There are hundreds of calculating models, each model will use different objects. A model may like:
Last five times，a1 < b1 and d1=1, so it use object A,B,D. Another model may use other objects.

So How to implement it in flink? I think I should split the input stream to each model, but I'm not sure. I'm new to flink, any idea is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to tell the most important aspect: what are you actually computing? Are you using each model independently or are they related? Do you use the same topology for each model? Which format are you using?

Comment: @ArvidHeise It's a alarm system. The input elements are double type. Each model is independent with others, it will produce an alarm message when it's evaluted true.

Comment: Is the model depending on the type of message or is it encoded in the message? Is the number of models dynamic or fixed? Btw please edit your question instead of responding to a comment.